# Error while inserting the values in database in asp.net for visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
</system.web>
```

register.aspx.cs file:-

```
protected void r_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C: \\Users\\Abhishek\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\S2N\\s2n\\App_Data\\Database.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into register values(@fname, @lname, @dob, @email, @mobile, @passoword)",conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname",fname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", fname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", dob.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mobile", mobile.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        fname.Text = "";
        lname.Text = "";
        dob.Text = "";
        email.Text = "";
        mobile.Text = "";
        password.Text = "";
        fname.Focus();
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Lots of issues with this code. 1) SqlConnection implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You should be creating it within a using statement. 2) [Don't use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) 3) It appears you're storing a plaintext password in your database. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted. Then you compare hashed forms of the password. Don't store plaintext passwords.

Comment: If you are not getting your connection string out of configuration then I suggest you use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` so you don't make a mistake in the syntax.

Comment: Ok @crowcoder, will implement SqlConnectionStringBuilder today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Typing @ before a string means that that string won't have any escape characters and that everything you type in it will be literal, so either remove the @ or remove the \\ and make it into \ in the connection string.
2. C: \\Users has a space between : and \, remove that too.

Try changing that.